# raphael. js create div on hover

Tags: javascript, raphael

Hi i need create a div (popUp) when over one state on a map with raphael.js, that div is:

```
<div class="marker">
    <img class="circle-marker" src="img/circle-marker.png" alt="hola">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <p class="state-name text-center">
        State name
    </p>
</div>
```

the js code is:

```
p.hover(function(){
    this.animate({
        fill: '#000'
    }, 200);
    // create the div
```

thanks!

Comment: Have you tried document.createElement('div'); I'm a little confused as to where you want the div though, as well as the p.hover, and its relationship to svg, so its likely the problem is more complicated. But I think you need to amend the question a little to highlight the svg and its relationship (maybe include a fiddle).

Comment: the fiddle is 
http://jsfiddle.net/xlsidlx/R5MP7/6/

Comment: Rather than adding a div each time, why not just have the div already in the dom and just change its style to hidden or not, you can then just change the statename text.

Comment: and now i only have a problem, the popup ever on the same position
http://jsfiddle.net/xlsidlx/86Bcy/1/